# Passive voice after the verbs "to order, command, tell, ask for"

Tags: passive-voice

I found the following sentences in an English language texbook (written by a non-native speaker) and I'm not sure about them. I've tried to find similar examples elsewhere, but couldn't. I think the sentences exist only in this book and not in real speech. Here they are:

> **1) He ordered the letter to be translated.**
>
> **2) I told the books to be brought.**
>
> **3) He asked for the dictionary to be brought.**

The question is: are they correct? Shouldn't it be something like:
**He ordered that the letter (should) be translated**?

Are these three sentences fine or wrong? Do native speakers construct sentences like that frequently?

Comment: Or [*He ordered it be {translated}*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+ordered+it+be%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), where I suppose that "bare infinitive" is "subjunctive". But you can't tell *books* to do anything - the verb ***tell*** doesn't work the same as ***order*** or ***ask***. I suppose in principle you could tell a slave to be bought, but it's pretty weird.

Comment: Certainly not with _tell_. Any NP following _tell_ will be interpreted as the addressee. _Ask_ can take a passive infinitive with a full _for..to_ complementizer (_He asked for it to be brought  = For it to be brought is what he asked_; both mean _He asked for them to bring it_). **With** the _for_ in _He asked for them to bring it_, the addressee of the request is indefinite; **without** the _for_, in _He asked them to bring it_, the addressee of the request was definitely _them_.

Comment: Dropping the "to" here sounds rather peculiar.  If you're going to use the subjective, it sounds better---at least to my ear---to use "that": "He order that the letter be translated", "He asked that the dictionary be brought". Both OK.  But in the original "dictionary" sentence, only dropping "to" sounds just plain wrong.

Comment: Ok, but what about _He ordered the letter to be translated_? How would you understand this sentence? Does it mean that he ordered **somebody** to translate the letter or the letter to translate itself? Is it a natural-sounding sentence?

Comment: @Starcatcher7: I assume we can rule out ordering letters and books to do things, since it doesn't make sense. I think some people would accept your version, but I'd rather go for *He ordered the letter be translated*, where there's an elided *ordered [that]...*, and an acceptable "subjunctive" (and an elided *...[should] be translated*, if it makes the construction any easier).

Comment: The original direct imperatives were, "The letters are to be translated." "The books are to be brought." and "The dictionary is to be brought."  I don't know if this is spell-casting or some sort of optative but I've certainly heard "The essay is to be on my desk by six o'clock."

Comment: Told doesn't work (agreed @FumbleFingers, sure).  It would have to be, "I specified...    "I decided...

Comment: "is to be..." is different than _told_, _ordered_ or _asked_. Granted, it's imperative, but the construction is formed differently. Essentially, "is to" means _must_, which can indeed apply to the dictionary, or the essay. But whatever verb applies to the person addressed (perhaps "bring"), it is unstated.

Answer (score 3):

The first two sentences are incorrect because they imply that the letter and books are being spoken to by a person *as if they themselves were the addressees*... The third sentence can be shortened without losing its meaning.

I would suggest the following:

1. He ordered that the letter be translated *or* He ordered the translation of the letter.
2. I requested that the books be brought *or simply* I asked for the books (with the understanding that they will be brought)
3. He asked for the dictionary (it will need to be fetched)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the books are being addressed by a person."

Answer (score -2):

See I may not know the name of the rules but I suggest you to look at the pattern of my answers below.

1) He ordered them to have the letter translated.

2) I asked to have the books brought.

3) He asked to have the dictionary brought.

Comment: ...the to... in the first example seems like a typing mistake. Shouldn't *the* be erased?

Comment: Of the 4 sentences in this answer, only sentence 3) (the 'dictionary' one) appears correct to me.

Comment: @Lucky: I think _the_ is supposed to be _them_. However, even with _them_ in place to salvage sentence 1, sentence 2 (as Hellion observes) is still fatally flawed because it lacks a direct object for _told_. And since the answerer doesn't provide an explanation for why the proposed wordings are correct, each one lives or dies solely on its own unadorned merits (or lack thereof). Ultimately, this answer isn't at all helpful, in my opinion.